# Weird message copied to iOS clipboard

Tags: ios, copy-paste

The following message suddenly got copied to my clipboard:

```
{"code":200,"data":{"bizTypeCode":"gz01","bizValue":"￥Ht0fYMlkyIl￥","bizTypeName":"淘口令"},"message":"处理成功","isSuccess":true}
```

What does this mean? iPhone XR, iOS 12.4

Comment: It looks like you copied a JSON string. It's just text and it's fairly easy to copy from the web. If your iPhone isn't jailbroken then I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: I do have some tweaked apps. Did it come from those?

Comment: It's almost impossible to say based on the info you've provided.  I don't know what you mean by "tweaked apps" but if you're not getting all your app from the Apple App Store then it's possible one of those apps put something on your clipboard.  My question would be why?  That's a fairly harmless text string.  Are you using Universal Clipboard from another Apple device, like a laptop?